# dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting (Impish an Hirsute)

Tags: apt, dpkg, 21.04

I installed several different versions of resent ubuntu releases and found that the Hirsute (21.04) and Impish (21.10) versions constantly get this error message.

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error
```

For example, when upgrading in Hirsute or installing packages in Impish.

(The older version 20.04 does not have this issue، At least as far as I tested، It was fine)

What could be the reason for this?

---

additional details:

upgradable

```
apt base-passwd gcc-11-base libapt-pkg6.0 libgcc-s1 libhogweed6 liblz4-1 libnettle8 libpam-modules-bin libpam-modules libpam-runtime libpam0g libprocps8 libstdc++6 libsystemd0 libudev1 login passwd procps
```

The following NEW packages will be installed:

```
 krb5-locales libgssapi-krb5-2 libk5crypto3 libkeyutils1 libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0 libnsl2 libssl1.1 libtirpc-common libtirpc3
```

The following packages will be upgraded:

```
apt base-passwd gcc-11-base libapt-pkg6.0 libgcc-s1 libhogweed6 liblz4-1 libnettle8 libpam-modules libpam-modules-bin libpam-runtime libpam0g libprocps8 libstdc++6 libsystemd0 libudev1 login passwd procps
```

19 upgraded, 10 newly installed.

Comment: 21.10 is off-topic. For 21.04 please provide exact reproducible list of steps to get mentioned error!

Comment: @N0rbert in the middle of ```upgrade``` I end up with this    ```dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting: unable to open directory '/var/lib/dpkg/updates/': Operation not permitted E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)``` The error message is very destructive. 21.04.

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1357641/edit) your question and include more context and details.  You should provide the complete commands you are running and the entire error. You must provide all of the steps taken to reproduce this error. Please do not add comments with terminal commands and output because it cannot be formatted properly.  Use the edit link so that we can parse the information.  Remember that we do not have access to your device so you must provide enough information to identify the problem. If we have to guess, we are not going to be able to answer effectively.

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For *impish* indri [21.10] questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu+1) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site (expected release date for Ubuntu 21.10 is 14 October 2021 (https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/impish-indri-release-schedule/18540) when your question will be on-topic here).

Comment: In comment you do provide parts of the *summary detail* for a command, but insufficient detail is provided (you only provided the summary that is provided earlier in the listing).  That detail should be provided complete so we can look up package issues, in your question (*and not in comment*).   What you've provided isn't enough to exclude user error(s).

Comment: @guiverc right after Installation of 21.04, update  and upgrade , it was like this ```19 upgraded, 10 newly installed``` in the middle of upgrade I end up with ```dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error```

Comment: @Nmath Not much to say. This was the first post-installation update/upgrade that I end up with an unrecoverable broken environment.

Comment: We cannot read the messages so cannot currently help; you providing the final summary (not from the program that had the errors; the *19 upgraded... newly installed* is a summary from the front-endcalling routine; the actual errors were earlier in the listing and where you need to look.  I'd look at the package name, check it's source (`apt-cache policy`) etc. but you've provided none of those details for us to help.  Please add additional details to your question, not in comments.

Comment: @guiverc for further investigation check additional details.

Comment: It's the error messages that are worked on; with full package details. You've provided only summary detail and not the actual problem packages, eg. for `krb5-locales` I'd expect `1.18.3-4` but you've not provided that detail which usually found in messages.

Comment: @guiverc The problem is somewhere in these packages. At least for Hirsute. 
 I have no more information because I had to reinstall the 20.04 version.